# drawable is not serializable exception

Tags: java, android, drawable

Hello I'm new to android development.
I try to make a list that takes 4 input fields and one photo.

The list should be saved in the internal storage but I'm getting this error:

```
java.io.notserializableexception android.graphics.drawable.bitmapdrawable;
```

Person bean class has 4 string variables and one Drawable.
Thanks for any help.

```
package com.example.awais_pc.savedataapp;

import android.app.Dialog; import android.content.Context; import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.ImageButton; import android.widget.ListView; import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream; import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java.io.FileOutputStream; import java.io.ObjectInputStream; import java.io.ObjectOutputStream; import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    String fileName = "data.txt";
    ArrayList<PersonBean> personBeans ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        readDataInFile();

}

    public void addRecord(View v ){
        myDialog();
    }
    public void myDialog(){
        final ImageButton imgbtn;
        final EditText name,pass,email,phone;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        name = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
         pass = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
         email = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        phone = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
          imgbtn = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        Button save = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String nam = name.getText().toString();
                String pas = pass.getText().toString();
                String em = email.getText().toString();
                String ph = phone.getText().toString();
                Drawable dra = imgbtn.getDrawable();
                personBeans.add(new PersonBean(nam,pas,em,ph,dra));
                listview.setAdapter(new Mycustomlist(personBeans, MainActivity.this));

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void writeDataInFile(){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(personBeans);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new Mycustomlist(personBeans, MainActivity.this));
    } // Write File

    private void readDataInFile(){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            personBeans = (ArrayList<PersonBean>)ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            personBeans = new ArrayList<PersonBean>();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new Mycustomlist(personBeans, MainActivity.this));

    }//Read File }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off-  beans are not used in Android.  Maybe you just named it that because you're used to doing so, but if you're actually trying to do beans in Android I suggest you start moving away from that concept entirely mentally.

Secondly, drawables aren't serializable.  If you're trying to serialize an object to a file via the serializable interface, it can't have a Drawable in it, or you'll have to write customized serializing functions.

Comment: No i just name it PersonBean
if i cant use Drawable then what should i use use i m new

Comment: You shouldn't be just blindly assuming anything can be serialized to disk.  What you should use instead-  probably a file system path of where to find the image.  Or an asset path.  A resource id would be dangerous as they may not be stable across versions.  A server url of where to download the image would also be acceptable.

Comment: you mean i have to do something like with ByteArray to store image ?

Comment: No, a Drawable is just fine for storing an image.  But a Drawable can't be written to disk via a Serializable call, because it doesn't implement Serializable.  Which means that if your object needs to hold drawables, you should probably not be taking the lazy way out and just using Serializable either, but actually think about a good way of storing that info.  Serializable is a nice quick hack, but it isn't and shouldn't be the default way of saving data to disk.

Comment: Then where should i save that image can you write some short code i would be thankful to you or is there any way to contact you in privvte msg or someting